# iOS, Graceful Orientation Change

Tags: ios, cgrect

I call this function at `viewDidLoad` and `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation`

```
-(void) makeBox{
    [self.view1 removeFromSuperview];

    float viewWidth = CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame);
    float viewHeight = CGRectGetHeight(self.view.frame);
    float startx = (viewWidth / 100) * 10;
    float starty = (viewHeight /100) * 20;

    float width = (viewWidth / 100) * 80;
    float height = (viewHeight /100) * 60;

    CGRect frame1 = CGRectMake(startx, starty, width, height);
    self.view1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame1];
    [self.view1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

    [self.view addSubview:self.view1];  
}
```

When the view does change, its very 'sketchy' & not very graceful at all. I'm using simulator but i assume that it would be the same if i were to run on a device. **How would i go about making this transition smoother?** I would post to user experiance page, but i wish todo this programmatically

The overall point of this, other than to learn, is to achieve orientation independent graphics from code (without autolayout).

Comment: Any particular reason why you're removing the view from its superview and then adding it again?

Comment: remove `view1` from the superview. well, surely not removing it would cause duplicate views...? this point of this is too make code-based graphics dynamic to orientation change

Comment: object initialization and allocation is a very costly procedure... why do you need to do this?

Comment: Use CGFloat, not float. It's there for a reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to remove the view and create a new one with the desired frame if its the only thing you're changing. Just modify the view frame in-place:

```
- (void)makeBox {
    CGFloat viewWidth = CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame);
    CGFloat viewHeight = CGRectGetHeight(self.view.frame);
    CGFloat startx = (viewWidth / 100) * 10;
    CGFloat starty = (viewHeight /100) * 20;

    CGFloat width = (viewWidth / 100) * 80;
    CGFloat height = (viewHeight /100) * 60;

    CGRect view1Frame = CGRectMake(startx, starty, width, height);

    if (!self.view1) {
        // The view doesn't exists yet, we create it
        self.view1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:view1Frame];
        [self.view1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        [self.view addSubview:self.view1];
    }
    else {
        // Just update the frame
        self.view1.frame = view1Frame;
    }
}
```

For extra-nice UX, wrap the frame update in an animation block:

```
// ... snip ...
else {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^() {
        self.view1.frame = view1Frame;
    }];
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure to understand what you're referring to with "something the user doesn't have to witness being done, even if it is in an extremely small space of time". Animate the change? If so, look at my edit.

Comment: Just read you're update! thats what i was after! :) i didn't like the way the user had to witness the width & height of the box sharply change. that animation is more like it!